# Failing to retrieve images depending on if localhost or remote server

Tags: html, image, localhost

I have an odd problem depending on whether I'm pointed to localhost, or a remote server.

When I refer to my localhost, my application (a map) works as I expect, on FF, Chrome, and IE10.  But, when I deploy the application to the shared dev server, I lose some images on FF and IE10, but not Chrome.

The source HTML is trivial:

Just a relative path, nothing fancy.

Firebug (edited) shows the following in the *requests*.

https://cantsaylocalhost.boisestate.edu/campusmap
GET /CampusMap/Content/images/generalMarker2.png HTTP/1.1

https://dev-web.boisestate.edu/campusmap
GET /Content/images/generalMarker2.png HTTP/1.1

notice the localhost Get path starts from the /campusmap root directory, while the dev-web Get path is different: it starts from a non-existent root /Content.

What gives?  Is there something I've never learned about how or if browsers deal with relative paths on localhosts vs remote? I'd originally thought it was something different about the servers (IIS), bur then differences should be in the Responses, not the Requests.

The test matrix looks like 
                  Chrome             IE10           Firefox               Firebug source
Localhost         OK                 OK             OK                   get /CampusMap/Content/images/icon
dev-web           OK                 missing        missing              get /Content/images/icon

The raw requests are:

Browser to localhost

GET /CampusMap/Content/images/generalMarker2.png HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0 FirePHP/0.7.2
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer:

Browser to remote

GET /Content/images/generalMarker2.png HTTP/1.1
Host: dev-web.boisestate.edu
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0 FirePHP/0.7.2
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://dev-web.boisestate.edu/campusmap
Cookie: __unam=95816f3-13cdea87ead-12f69a5e-34; __utma=124011033.771840282.1365534309.1367510743.1367517351.11; __utmz=124011033.1365534309.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmc=124011033
x-insight: activate
Connection: keep-alive

Ideas? I'm stuck, naturally.

Comment: Is this the only relative path that is breaking? From what I can see, it looks like the dev-web page believes that the whole page is being served from the campusmap directory and so is simply sending out for resources below that directory, while your other localhost page is served from a directory above the campusmap directory and so generates a different get url when resolving the relative path.

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back.  The answer to your question is yes, it's the only path that's breaking, but that's possibly because it's the only place I need to do this.    However, I'll take a stab, because if where you were going was to put the whole path, beginning with campusmap minus the http reference, than that's actually what worked.   And it's probably exactly as you say, the two servers are serving from a different directory, and need more information than I originally supplied.